# Force a 5 GHz connection on an iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone

My wife and I both have 5s and both connect to BT Home Hub on default settings. Through the hub I can see she is connected using 5 GHz but I am connected using 2.4 GHz. How can I make mine use 5 GHz, at least as a preference?

Answer (score 3):

iOS decides automatically whether 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz connection is best if an access point supports both.

You can change your BT Home Hub settings to broadcast two separate access points. Open the hub settings → Advanced Settings → Wireless → 5 GHz Wireless and disable “Sync with 2.4 GHz”.

[image]

This allows you to specifically connect to two separate access points depending on whether you wish to connect over 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz.